# Does "Varones" only refer to men?

Tags: vocabulario, definiciones

Does the Spanish word "Varones" only refer to men or can it include women in its definition as well? From my understanding it only means males/men. But I want to make sure about this. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not that related to what you are asking, but just in case "Todos los barones son varones, pero no todos los varones son barones." [Barón](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=UHwU7bUzkDXX2BgmWgas) is a title and the word is an homonym with _varón_.

Comment: Short answer: Yes

Answer (score 8):

That is correct. *varón* refers exclusively to males when used to refer to humans.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @JohnB Please select a correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

A *varón* is, indeed, a male human. Currently, this word is only used to emphasize the sex of the person we are talking about, so it would translate to *male* in English on most situations.

The word *hombre*, on the contrary, can be used for a male human or in a generic sense, much as the word *man* is used in English, for the human species or unspecified people:

> El hombre habita la Tierra desde hace un millón de años (*generic; it includes men and women*).
>
> El hombre es el más longevo de los mamíferos (*generic; it refers to the species, regardless of sex*).
>
> Deseo la paz entre todos los hombres (*generic, once again*).

Comment: I'm afraid that's not correct. You cannot use "hombre" for a person without specifying its sex. If you talk about a "hombre" you are always talking about a male human being.

Comment: @AlbertoMartín Not always. From a zoological point of view, we are all *hombres*. If you talk about the *evolución del hombre* (*evolution of man*), or the *obras del hombre* (*works of man*), you are not specifying sex. And if you say that an Army company holds *cien hombres* (*a houndred men*), you are not specifying sex, either.

 On the other hand, if you say *He visto un hombre en la calle* (*I saw a man in the street*), you do indeed mean a male person. But this is the way the word *man* works in English, too.

Comment: @AlbertoMartín Anyway, I've inserted a *sometimes* in my answer to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: That's true when you talk about mankind, but NEVER when you talk about a person, as you state. Even if you insert the "sometimes", it's wrong. In your example: "He visto un hombre en la calle" The person CANNOT be a woman, you are wrong, I'm sorry.

Comment: @AlbertoMartín That's what I say: *He visto un hombre en la calle* refers to a male person. Anyway, I see your point. I wil rewrite my last paragraph.

Comment: You are right, that example was correct, I misread it.